# Is there a word for, ‘the need to say something’?

Tags: single-word-requests

Having the urge to say something  (can’t help myself or  have to say something about a comment another person has stated)

Comment: If what you are trying to suppress goes against your own moral compass, use *compulsion*. If not, then *urge* would be more than sufficient.

Comment: @Kris "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered." <-- And that's not an opinion or an argument. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @Kris it lacks research as well as an example sentence. Hence its closure.

Comment: @Kris it says so at the bottom of the question. Although, *'If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.
'*. I think you are more than welcome to add the *'everything'* you have in mind concerning research and example sentences.

Answer (score -2):

*Declare* comes close. *Attest* is similar, too.